# Navigation doesn't working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have a problem with a screen and its navigation menu.
When I push the viewcontroller, it appears ok[image]

But when I go back, this put a blank space at the top of my screen(the gray space is a image, don't worry about it)

[image]

I don't know what the problem is, all my screens have their .xib but this one not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you pushing it to the navigation stack? please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like to be a problem with the topLayoutGuide, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide).

You need to set the frame of the view controller's view, when it appears, to

```
(0.0, topLayoutGuide.length, width, height)
```

to place the view directly below the navigation bar.